# How to set active Tab by ID?

Tags: java, android

The current method is tabHost.setCurrentTab(index) by index but I want to use ID for Tab for this operation.

Any body can tell me it is possible?

Comment: What kind of ID are you referring to? A view ID? That wouldn't really make sense, because a `TabHost` does not directly interact with views. In stead, it uses `TabSpec`. Either you select the tag by the index of its `TabSpec`, or by tag. Normally you wouldn't use the latter yourself, so the index-based one remains.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify yours question in a more descriptive way any way what i understand on the basis of that please look on the code

```
intent = new Intent(this, HomeGroup.class);
    View tab1 = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_1,null);
    homeTab.setTag("Tab1");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(tab1).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    View tab2 = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_2,null);
    homeTab.setTag("Tab2");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(tab2).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    View tab3 = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_3,null);
    homeTab.setTag("Tab3");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator(tab3).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    //click on seleccted tab
    int numberOfTabs = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();
    for(int t=0; t<numberOfTabs; t++){
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(t).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                    String currentSelectedTag = MainTab.this.getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag();
                    String currentTag = (String)v.getTag();
                    Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "currentSelectedTag: " + currentSelectedTag + " currentTag: " + currentTag);
                    if(currentSelectedTag.equalsIgnoreCase(currentTag)){
                        MainTab.this.getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(currentTag);
                        String newSelectedTabTag = MainTab.this.getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag();
                        if(newSelectedTabTag.toLowerCase().indexOf("tab1")!=-1){
                            //do smthg
                        }else if(newSelectedTabTag.toLowerCase().indexOf("tab1")!=-1){
                            //do smthg
                        }else if(newSelectedTabTag.toLowerCase().indexOf("tab3")!=-1){
                            //do smthg
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you your reply, but it is not work for me because I need to switch different tab by ID when start activity by parameter.  But your answer need to monitor action after activity startup.